# How to calculate the area of a lake using binary image?

Tags: matlab, area

Matlab - At I'm trying to use is the following:

1. Load image, transform to binary ; Using BWboundaries.
2. Find edge/perimeter ;
3. Attempt to join edges ;
4. Fill perimeter with red ;
5. Measure Area and Perimeter using regionprops
6. Plot line horizontal or vertical ;
7. Stipulate value of axis of that coordinates on the edges, and distance in pixels (after converting for meters).

[image]

Comment: What is your code so far, and what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image that you have posted already segmented why don't you just count your black pixels? This is going to give you the area.

Otherwise take a look at `regionprops` of Matlab (http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hc)